# Are there ux guide(image/sound) on google assistant?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm works with google assistant  partner sdk(c++) to integrate google assistant to our tv device.

I have question about google assistant ux guide. Is there a default resouce(sound,image )  have to use?

Amazon Alexa has a ux  guide for partners. sounds and images are served to partner product developer also.
for example, alexa give file of ding sound when microphone start to recording after hotword(alexa) spoken.

My question is. Those default ux (sound) guide is existed on google assistant?

Comment: Something like this? 
https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/conversation/#

Comment: If you are using the partner SDK, you should ask your contacts at Google for such content.